# Как реализовать в Unity3D HTML браузер?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Подскажите, как в Юнити реализовать простой `HTML` браузер? Желательно средствами C#.

Браузер должен рендерить страничку из строки с html-кодом (к примеру, диалог с NPC). Загрузка из сети не обязательна.

В инетах поискал, но ни чего дельного не нашел, однако в некоторых играх на Юнити простейший браузер присутствует.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Awesomium (http://www.awesomium.com/). Начиная с версии 1.7 веб текстура не отображается в Editor, дебажить очень сложно, только логирование, а на логах далеко не уедешь.
   Более ранние версии работают отлично, но по ряду других причин, ранние версии не подходят.
2. uWebKit(http://uwebkit.com/). Этого зверя довольно просто интегрировать в проект, но есть одно но, при просмотре видео, он почти вымирает, ролик отображается приблизительно 5 кадров в секунду. Вырви глаз, короче. Еще он отказывается работать YouTube Api (JavaScript), а это по специфике необходимо.
3. Coherent UI (http://coherent-labs.com/) Пожалуй лучший кандидат, работает шустро, дружит с YouTube Api, но не умеет открывать ссылки которые должны открыться в новом окне. (Вводим на google.ru запрос, пытаем нажать на результат, а эффекта болт)

Вот ещё инфа на хабре : http://habrahabr.ru/post/220183/
а это пример управления браузером из встроенных скриптов в юнити : 
К примеру послать JavaScript в браузер ваш : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.ExternalCall.html

А это к примеру вернуть страничку назад стандартной кнопкой в юнити :
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.ExternalEval.html

Answer (score 1):

Использовали в своем проекте относительно новый плагин
[Embedded Browser](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/55459) - который интегрирует в `Unity 3D` браузер на базе `Chromium` и позволяет накладывать страницу на любую поверхность mesh, в том числе использовать в `UI`. Можно проигрывать видео с `Youtube`, загружать странички со встроенного локального сервера. Лучше один раз увидеть, загрузите демку и увидите все богатые возможности плагина.
Правда есть и ложка дегтя, в некоторых проектах при отладке при наличии браузера наблюдалось зависание Unity.

Comment: Выглядит классненько, спасибо! Как у него дела с производительностью и современным html5/css3, поддерживает ли флекс-бокс? Есть задумка использовать html с простой версткой в качестве диалогов с неписью.

Comment: Производительность не проседает. Мы использовали в проекте до 20 окон одновременно с html и видео роликами тормозов было не больше чем при запуске тех же окон в браузере. По остальному не скажу, мы так глубоко с ним не погружались